# how to compare two multi-line texts regardless of any empty spaces, new lines and tab character

Tags: c#

```
if (text1 == null) return string.IsNullOrEmpty(text1);
if (text2 == null) return string.IsNullOrEmpty(text2);
text1 = text1.Replace("\n", string.Empty).Replace("\r\n", string.Empty).Replace(" ", string.Empty).Replace(Environment.NewLine, string.Empty);
text2 = text2.Replace("\n", string.Empty).Replace("\r\n", string.Empty).Replace(" ", string.Empty).Replace(Environment.NewLine, string.Empty);
return text1 == text2;
```

Comment: this code is not returning the correct boolean value, I have searched similar questions but still not a close answer.

Comment: Please elaborate, because the actual question or problem you have seems to be missing.

Comment: the two texts may have different lengths, but I only care about the non-white space contents of these two texts. to compare if their contents are equal

Comment: This doesn't make sense: `if (text1 == null) return string.IsNullOrEmpty(text1);`. Instead you can return `true`

Comment: I have two large multi-line texts, names text1 and text2, I want to determine if these two texts has equal contents regardless of any empty spaces, new lines and tab characters.

Comment: You mention tabs in your question but you are not removing horizontal tabs in the example (`\t`)

Comment: the method was invoked with text1 = you your and text2 = you your .......it should return true but returning false;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not need the whitespace to match, you could define a function that compares strings excluding whitespace:

```
static bool EqualsExcludingWhitespace(String a, String b) {
    return a.Where(c => !Char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
       .SequenceEqual(b.Where(c => !Char.IsWhiteSpace(c)));
}
```

Comment: @RoyGuzman if this answer was helpful to you, please accept it and vote it up :) you are welcome

Comment: I think I just did, how can I close the question as answered!

Comment: @RoyGuzman it's enought accept it as answered as you did allready :)

Answer (score 0):

A `Regex` will work for this:

```
static bool Compare(string text1, string text2)
{
    if (text1 == null || text2 == null)
        return true; // this is what your code does, although to be honest it is odd

    text1 = Regex.Replace(text1, @"\s+", "");
    text2 = Regex.Replace(text2, @"\s+", "");
    return text1 == text2;
}
```